# Single Microphone System with PTT

Tags: microphone

I'm brand new to looking at audio/sound systems, so I'm starting scratch on this one.  I'm looking at a project where I'd like to have a panel mount microphone that turns on with push-to-talk.  Having never spec'd microphone systems, I'm unsure as to what kind of microphone, PTT, and amplifier I might need.  I'm trying to keep it cheap but effective.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction on what to look at?

Thanks in advance!